# difference seen in difftime and strftime values

Tags: c++, time, mktime

I'm seeing a difference in time functions and was wondering what was the reason. 
currently, I'm using localtime, mktime, strftime and difftime:

```
time_t ltime; 
ltime = time(NULL); 
StartTM = localtime(&ltime); 
time_t time1 = mktime(StartTM ); 
char startbuffer [128]; 
strftime( start_buffer, 128, "%H:%M:%S", StartTM ); 
<<Do some stuff, take some time >>>
time_t ttime; 
ttime = time(NULL); 
StopTM = localtime(&ttime); 
time_t time2 = mktime(StopTM ); 
char stop_buffer [128]; 
strftime( stop_buffer, 128, "%H:%M:%S:", StopTM ); 
double wtinsec = difftime(time2, time1);
```

Executed, the output looks like this:

Stop buffer=08:46:18

Start buffer=08:44:11

wtinsec=129

Subtracting start from stop by hand, the length of time is 2:07, however the total number of seconds (difftime) says 2:09.  As both times are using the same raw data (time1, time2) for both calculations, my initial thoughts was combination of lack of precision in the strftime conversion and difftime is the cause of this.

But the difference is not constant.  If the time between the 2 local calls is small (like 10 seconds) there is no difference.  However, as the time between the 2 time calls gets longer, the difference in time totals becomes larger.  At 2 mins, its 2 seconds at 5 mins its 4 seconds and so on...

Any reason why this is happening and is there anything more accurate (in C++) preferably in micro/milliseconds that can track time of day and subtract one from another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The values in `ltime` and `time1` should be identical; the round trip through `localtime()` and `mktime()` should give you the answer you started with.  Similarly, of course, for `ttime` and `time2`.

This C code demonstrates the expected behaviour.  You need to look hard at your code to find out what is going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{

    time_t     ltime = time(NULL); 
    struct tm *start = localtime(&ltime); 
    time_t     time1 = mktime(start); 
    char startbuffer[128]; 
    strftime(startbuffer, sizeof(startbuffer), "%H:%M:%S", start); 
    printf("lt = %10lu, t1 = %10lu, time = %s\n",
           (unsigned long)ltime, (unsigned long)time1, startbuffer);

    sleep(10);

    time_t     ttime = time(NULL); 
    struct tm *finis = localtime(&ttime); 
    time_t     time2 = mktime(finis); 
    strftime(startbuffer, sizeof(startbuffer), "%H:%M:%S", finis); 
    printf("lt = %10lu, t1 = %10lu, time = %s\n",
           (unsigned long)ttime, (unsigned long)time2, startbuffer);

    printf("diff time = %.2f\n", difftime(time2, time1));

    return(0);
}
```

Sample output (from Mac OS X 10.7.5):

```
lt = 1358284665, t1 = 1358284665, time = 13:17:45
lt = 1358284675, t1 = 1358284675, time = 13:17:55
diff time = 10.00
```

I recommend looking at the values in your code, similar to the way I did.  You might (or might not) print out the contents of the `struct tm` structures.  It would be worth making a function to handle the 7-line block of repeated code; you'll need it to return `time1` and `time2`, of course, so you can do the difference in the 'main' code. Also remember that `localtime()` may return the same pointer twice; you can't reliably use the start time structure after you've called `localtime()` with the finish time.